# How to check if item has already existed in Listbox Windows Phone 8.1 Universal

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

Here is my XAML code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyList">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>  
            <Grid>                                             
                 <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                            Text="{Binding MyText}" />
            </Grid>  
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Does anyone please tell me how to  check if item has already existed in Listbox?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you added the items using `MyList.Items.Add("Test");`you can use this:

```
bool contained = MyList.Items.Contains("Test");
```

Or if the ListBox contains a user-defined class instead of a string:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}

bool contained = MyList.Items.Cast<TestClass>().Any(x => x.MyText == "Test");
```

Better would be to use `MVVM` design pattern and `DataBinding`